# 'InvalidIndexError' when concatenating netCDF files as a dataset using python xarray

Tags: python, database, dataframe, concatenation, python-xarray

I want to concatenate 50 netCDF files in my directory using python **xarray** 'open_mfdataset'. It works with a small selection of netCDF files but not when concatenating all 50. I get this error when calling the function from 'toolbox.py' in a script 'demo.py':

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('data_dir/demo.py', wdir='')
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "data_dir/demo.py", line 15, in 
>       data_files = concat(data_dir,chunks,file_name)
>
> File "Python/toolbox.py", line 53, in
>   concat
>       data_vars='minimal',parallel=False).chunk(chunks)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py",
>   line 719, in open_mfdataset
>       ids=ids)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py",
>   line 553, in _auto_combine
>       data_vars=data_vars, coords=coords)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py",
>   line 475, in _combine_nd
>       compat=compat)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py",
>   line 493, in _auto_combine_all_along_first_dim
>       data_vars, coords)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/combine.py",
>   line 514, in _auto_combine_1d
>       merged = merge(concatenated, compat=compat)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py",
>   line 532, in merge
>       variables, coord_names, dims = merge_core(dict_like_objects, compat, join)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py",
>   line 445, in merge_core
>       aligned = deep_align(coerced, join=join, copy=False, indexes=indexes)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py",
>   line 217, in deep_align
>       exclude=exclude)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py",
>   line 133, in align
>       index = joiner(matching_indexes)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 2223, in **or**
>       return self.union(other)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py",
>   line 493, in union
>       result = Index.union(this, other)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 2332, in union
>       indexer = self.get_indexer(other)
>
> File
>   "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 2740, in get_indexer
>       raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
>
> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index
>   objects

I have tried looking at individual netCDF files and tried different selections of netCDF files for concatenation. I think it might be because there are more than one index objects that are the same? but I don't really understand it.

```
def concat(data_dir,chunks,file_name):
    # data_dir = directory where IMOS glider .nc files exist
    # chunks = output variable 'chunks' from function 'find_chunks' - this is a single value
    # file_name = specify string for name of file (not including extension e.g. '.zarr')

    # concatenate IMOS glider netCDF files in data_dir
    data_files = xr.open_mfdataset(data_dir + '*.nc', concat_dim='TIME',data_vars='minimal',parallel=False).chunk(chunks)
    print('Data concatenated..')

    # I then save the concatenated dataset as a netCDF and .zarr. This only works for smaller slections of netCDF files.

    return data_files
```

I expect a concatenated dataset that I can return from the function and save as a netCDF and .zarr file.

Comment: Dear UpperEastSide, I usually apply the same code as yours for a concatenation between Netcdfs in Python. The only difference is that the "chunks" argument is inside the "xr.open_mfdataset" function. Also, chunks argument should be a dictionary containing the size of each dimension per label specifically. If possible, try that alteration, and let us know what worked best. Sincerely, Philipe